# How can a MOSFET can be used as resistor and capacitor

Tags: mosfet, fabrication

How can a MOSFET be used as a resistor or capacitor?

Please explain this line:
"The DS channel of MOSFET can serve as a resistor."

Comment: think about it .... what does a resistor do in an electric circuit?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EE.SE. EE.SE tends to avoid answering homework questions for you, and encourages you to use reason and other sources to find the answer yourself. My tip would be: A resistor has a linear IV-curve, how can you use a mosfet to approximate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a MOSFET is in the ON state, it has low (Rdson) resistance, when it is in the off state, it has very high resistance (meghoms to gigaohms, but they tend to have roughly stable leakage current over their operating voltage range).

By applying a gate voltage lower than a MOSFET'S Vgson but higher than it's minimum conduction threshold, you will cause it to have a resistance higher than it's Rdson and lower than it's off state resistance, and in this way, you can use it as a variable resistor, with dissipation capability determined by chip specs, packaging and cooling.

A capacitor is a set of paralell conductive plates separated by a dielectric barrier.  Capacitance is directly proportional to surface area and inversely proportional to the distance between the plates.  This is effectively what a mosfet is in it's off state, although it is not constructed specifically to have high paralell surface area conductors and a physically thin gap.  Varying the gate voltage below the conduction threshold will vary the thickness of the nonconductive gap, effectively creating a voltage controlled capacitor/switch.

Comment: As Resistor in triode region where it is  Linear  in Id vs Vds graph

Comment: If you want an AC resistor this is not the solution. Just saying.

Comment: It is really not the best capacitor either, but the question is how it can be done.  It would be possible to use a set for AC purposes too, just more complicated and with the same caveats.  The question is how can it be done, but it can be used as either because it is either.

Comment: Adding to the answer, MOSFETs as CAPs or in short MOSCAPs are used mainly as decoupling caps between supply and ground. I.e. Supply Voltage (which is typically above Vth of MOSFET) is connected to gate and S & D connected to GND. As you can observe, the gate oxide (dielectric) , Gate (1st parallel plate) and Channel (2nd Parallel plate) acts as capacitor and its when MOSFET is "ON"

Comment: These MOS CAPS are used as varactors to tune Voltage-controlled oscillators. You cell phone may use them in the channel selection circuits.

Comment: So if the gate capacitor is being used as the active capacitance how do they manipulate the capacitance?  Is the ability to manipulate capacitance indeed the reason you would use one rather than a purpose designed capacitor?